Ifs Information[] (aka ??) fragile for large lists? Stuck kernel using ?? largeList
I discovered that running the following in a fresh kernel seemed to result in a stuck or very lengthy computation time.
data = RandomReal[{-1,1},{10^3,10^3}];(*this is fine*)
?? data 
(*this is running forever, oh wait finished after 10 minutes*)

If I instead used 10^2 in each dimension it only took a moment or two. What seems to be happening is that the standard protections against large output are not in effect when using ??, but I could be wrong. Is this intended behavior?

Update by (Nasser)
Important.
Make sure to save all your work before trying this. This caused Mathematica to hang for me and I had to kill all of Mathematica to get out

Yes, confirm this in V 14 on windows. It also generates "formatting notebook content:" type message. Looks like front end hangs displaying on this large data (1000 by 1000 content for some reason.  Make sure to tell users to save their work before trying this, as I had to kill Mathematica to stop the hang!

oh wait finished after 10 minutes that is too long to wait for most people :)

I'm so sorry!! I hope you didn't lose anything important! I totally meant to warn people! and yeah I only waited that long(ish) because I was typing up the problem here and trying to do my due diligence looking in the documentation and such.

Do not worry, I did not lose any work. I had just started Mathematica and had nothing running.

oh hey an even better way to Brick MMA is to do ??Out , (will cause MMA to be unresponsive unless you have $HistoryLength small or just started a session. )
